# Interactive Table Tree Structure (Datatable) in Django Bootstrap4 & Ajax

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a project model that can have WBS and activities, WBS can also have activities.
I want to load it in a tree table style so the user can edit any one record from one screen. Is it possible in Django?

I have tried using datatable examples which are great but what to do if I wish to load a tree like structure and use Ajax to Add/Update?